# How to call a shell alias from popen()

Tags: c, alias, popen

I have a .c file that uses popen to call an alias "foo" to get a file containing a string.
However, when i (compile and) execute the code I get the error "sh: 1: foo: not found".
How can I define the alias foo so that the code can run it as well?
I tried putting the alias definition in the ~/.bashsr without success.

Code excerpt:

```
FILE *f;
if ((f = popen("foo", "r")) == NULL) exit(1);
if (getline(&flag, &fl, f) < 0) exit(1);
pclose(f);
```

Comment: Did you try running `alias foo=/bin/bash`?

Comment: If you put it in your file, try `source ~/.bashsr`

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases

Comment: Just another reason not to use aliases…you have to work to make them available all the time.